# Why is Prince Pondicherry absent from "Willy Wonka and the Chocolate Factory"?

Tags: plot-explanation, willy-wonka-and-chocolate-factory

Is there any reason why Prince Pondicherry (a character from Roald Dahl's novel "Charlie and the Chocolate Factory") is absent from "Willy Wonka and the Chocolate Factory"?

Answer (score 7):

Budget cuts, if [this *Los Angeles Times* article](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-2005-feb-06-ca-chocolate6-story.html) is to be believed:

> “Willy Wonka & the Chocolate Factory” undeniably left a fair amount of its source material behind. There is neither a visit to the book’s whangdoodle-infested jungles of Loompaland, nor a glimpse of Prince Pondicherry’s melting chocolate palace. With only $3 million to spend, Stuart also ditched Roald’s nut-cracking squirrels, opting instead for a golden egg-laying goose.